# Ruby on Rails Scope calculated data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, scope, calculated-field

I have a `User` and `Shop` moodel. Relationship is: `User has_many :shops`.

There is a scope in `User` model:

```
scope :order_by, ->(order_by) { order("#{order_by} DESC") }
```

How can I sort users by `shops` count?

Like

```
<%= select_tag(:order_by, options_for_select([["Name", "name"], ["E-mail", "email"], 
                                                ["Shops count", "user.shops.count"], 
                                                ["Date of creation", "created_at"]],
                                                 "Date of creation")) %>
```

Comment: this might be a little weird, but it's what i could think of, try something like this `scope :order_by_shops, ->{ includes(:shops).select(:*, "count('users.shops') as shops_count").order('shops_count DESC')`

Comment: Mohammad, no, doesn't work. No mistakes, just doesn't work.

Comment: Did you check the data? Does the count exist in the set? Or is it just un sorted?

Comment: I think we need to add a group, try `scope :order_by_shops, ->{ includes(:shops).select(:*, "count('users.shops') as shops_count").group('users.id').order('shops_count DESC')`

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
User.left_joins(:shops).group(:id).order('COUNT(shops.id) DESC')
```